# AngularJS, $resource and PHP errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a REST PHP API to get some data, and I use AngularJS $resource to gather them.

When a PHP Error occurs after a $save, the function called is not the error callback but the success callback, and the object become an array of chars with the PHP error.
Since the object is actually destroyed that way, I loose the original data.

Is there a way to make $resource to see errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On error, your API needs to return status other than 2xx. If you take a look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L119) you may find that success callback will be called only if following condition is met:

```
200 <= status && status < 300
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't think to check the source.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the error in PHP and return proper error code using php Use the header function to return error codes, like this:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
```